# Flutter add List<int> to List<List>

Tags: flutter, list, arraylist, stateful

I have statefull widget, I want to create list of number and then ad them aslist onanother list,

I initialize the list
`    late List digits;
late List listOfDigits;

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    digits = [];
     listOfDigits = [];
    super.initState();
}`
```

I have textfiled with controller name = number, and button to add the number to digits list :
`digits.add(int.parse(number.text)); setState(() {});`

and another button to add digits list to listOfDigits and clear digits list:

```
    listOfDigits.add(digits)
    digits.clear();
    setState(() {});
```

firs time create list of digits I get : [[]]
when I create second digis like [1,8,-9] I get : [[1,8,-9]]
for thisrd time any digit (for example 7) add to digits it add otamitcly to both list and be like this :
[[1,8,-9,7],[1,8,-9,7]]

I tried same thing with provider I get same result

Comment: this is because you are adding the same list every time, instead of `digits.clear()` use `digits ≠ []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that objects are "[pass by reference](https://www.educative.io/answers/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference)" in Dart (and mostly all languages).

`digits` and `listOfDigits` are both **instances** of type `List`. When you do `listOfDigits.add(digits)`, you are adding that same instance of `digits` to the list every time. When you do `digits.clear()`, you remove all the items inside it, and since `listOfDigits` holds a reference to that same instance of `digits`, it is empty too.

What you can do to fix that is to create a copy (a new instance) of the list of integers and pass that to the `listOfDigits`, so that when you clear `digits`, you don't clear the one inside of `listOfDigits`.

You can do that by either using `List.from` or creating a new list for `digits`.

[`List.from`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-core/List/List.from.html):

```dart
// List.from creates a new list with the same values as `digits`.
listOfDigits.add(List.from(digits)); 
digits.clear();
setState(() {});
```

New list:

```dart
listOfDigits.add(digits);
// Here, instead of clearing the same list inside `listOfDigits`,
// you are simply creating a new one for that variable (and keeping
// the old instance unmodified).
digits = [];
setState(() {});
```